# Unable to add window - token android.os.BinderProxy@41b70320 is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog

iam trying to develop an app but when i touch BACK button the system shows Unable to add window - token android.os.BinderProxy@41b70320 is not valid; is your activity running? 
i don't understand, how i can solve it?
My dialog has been created with AsyncTask
my code:
the class (it is not complete, because is very big)

```
 public class VistaJuego extends View {


Drawable drawableFaba,drawableFabaMinera,drawableFabaAstur, drawableBotellasAbajo,drawableBotellasArriba,aux,botellaRota;
Grafico faba;
Vector<Grafico> botellasAbajo,botellasArriba;
int numeroBotellas = 2;
static int PERIODO_PROCESO = 50;
ThreadJuego juego = new ThreadJuego();
ThreadFaba hiloFaba= new ThreadFaba();
int alto,ancho,altoPantalla;//alto del canvas
MainActivity main;
Boolean ifmusica,ifvibracion;
Activity activity;
Async a;
public void gestionarChoque(Grafico elementofaba,Grafico elementoBotella){

    boolean guardado=false;
    if((elementofaba.getPosX()+elementofaba.getAncho()>=elementoBotella.getPosX()+15)){
        juego.detener();
        hiloFaba.detener();
        if(ifmusica==true){
            sonidoJuego.stop();
            golpe.start();
        }
        if(ifvibracion==true){
            v.vibrate(200);
        }


        elementoBotella.setDrawable(botellaRota);
        if(guardado==false){
            bd.guardarPuntuacion(marcador.getPuntos()+1, faba.hacerFecha());
            guardado=true;
        }   

        a= new Async((Activity) getContext());
        a.execute();

        Log.i("Guardó de VistaJuego", "guardado abajo");
    }
```

and the activity

```
public class AngryJuego extends Activity {

RelativeLayout relative;
public int anchoPantalla, altoPantalla;
VistaJuego vistafaba;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
Boolean brillo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.angry_juego);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    altoPantalla=display.getHeight();

    RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
    vistafaba=(VistaJuego)findViewById(R.id.faba);
    relative=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
    vistafaba.setAltoPantalla(altoPantalla);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)){


        Intent i= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(i);


    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

HELP ME please is for my job and i don't undestand nothing....

Comment: How do you instantiate your dialog? most likely your dialog is created when the application has been closed, thus the parent activity is already destroyed and the app cannot find the correct parent for the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the AsyncTask class because the "if" was not correct. With this code it works.

```
public class Async extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{


    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    Activity contexto;
    WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;

    public Async(Activity context) {
        activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
        contexto=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (activityWeakRef != null  && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityWeakRef.get());
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.si,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    Intent i= contexto.getIntent();
                                    contexto.finish();
                                    contexto.startActivity(i);

                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {

                                    Intent i= new Intent(contexto,MainActivity.class);
                                    contexto.startActivity(i);
                                }
                            });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }
```